# How to reliably retrieve product attribute data?

Tags: woocommerce

On a site where I started with WooCommerce version 2.*.* and then upgraded through newer releases (3.0.0, 3.0.1, ... 3.0.4), I'm noticing an inconsistency in how the order item meta data is stored for product attributes.

When using an attribute "Class Date" for variations, when an order is placed for some products in the store, the meta data for Class Date is stored using the key "pa_class-date".  But for other products, the data for that same attribute is stored using the key "class-date".

My code for fetching attribute data looks like this:

```
$items = $order->get_items();
if ( isset($item['item_meta']['class-date']) ) {
    $class_date = $item['item_meta']['class-date'];
} elseif ( isset($item['item_meta']['pa_class-date']) ) {
    $class_date    = $item['item_meta']['pa_class-date'];
} else {
    error_log("Missing class date. We tried pa_class-date and class-date, but both are empty");
}
```

I would like to be able to simplify this to just look in one key or the other (pa_class-date or class-date, not both). Is that possible?

Here is what a dump of the order meta data looks like for the purchase of two different products. This one uses pa_class-date.

```
[467] => stdClass Object
    (   
        [key] => pa_class-date
        [value] => 2017-09-01
        [display_key] => Class Date
        [display_value] => <p>2017-09-01</p>

    )
```

But for a different product, the data stored using the key "class-date":

```
26-Apr-2017 16:26:06 UTC] Array
(
    [480] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => class-date
            [value] => 2017-05-18
            [display_key] => Class Date
            [display_value] => <p>2017-05-18</p>

        )
```

What causes the inconsistency in which key is used to store the data?

What is the most reliable (futureproof) way to retrieve the data?

Comment: Heads up that `$order->get_items();` now returns and array of `$item` *object* and you should start using the getter methods on it in lieu of accessing it like an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inconsistency is possible. But its inconsistent data entry rather. When you add attribute to Products >> Attributes, they become part of woocommerce system. Then you can map them to variation by just selecting on product details page.

However, when you add "Custom Attribute" directly from product details page, that data will be specific for that product and can cause inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. I deleted the attribute from the classes that were using "class-date" as the key then added the attributes back using Product >> Attributes then configured the variations again. After that, the product now stores the data using pa_class-date.

Comment: I am glad it helped!